# How to create object when you read multiples lines from files and send response using nodejs sendFile?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am logging messages to files from one of the server , now for client side they are required to download files so in below code i am sending file content to download when its a single message file is being downloaded but when its multiple messages in file its throwing exception on client side unexpected token because json is invalid,I added how filesdata look like in my qestion. How can i send these messages as json object `[{},{}]` when i sendFile content to client ?

app.js

```
app.get('/file', function (req, res) {
    var dir = './ditLogs';
    var root = path.resolve('./ditLogs');
    var fileName = req.query.file_name;
    var data;
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, items) {
        items.forEach(function(file){
            if(fileName === file){
                data = file;
                console.log('DATA',data);
                res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'application/json','attachment; filename=' + data);
                res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
                res.sendFile(data, {root: root});
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

fileData

```
{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}
{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}
{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put comma and root with braces.

See this example:

```
{"logs" : [{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"},
       {"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"},
       {"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}
]}

//To resolve your issue. Declare a variable say 
var container ="{"logs" : ["; //start tag
// append the content
container += "" + {'level':'info','message':'Test Log1  messages'} + "";
container += "" + {'level':'info','message':'Test Log2  messages'} + "";
container += "]}"; // end tag
```

// you can then use the string "container"

Comment: That is understood it needs valid json but how can i do that dynamically when i am reading data and sending it to client