# sendFile is throwing exception invalid json?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, express

I am sending file to client to download but when i receive below data from file its throwing exception json invalid , Is there any other approach to send file like `res.download` and set content as json. I am looking for better approach to send file without using angularJs FileSaver it should populate dialog to the browser, is it possible to acheive this using nodejs ?

app.js

```
app.get('/file', function (req, res) {
    var dir = './ditLogs';
    var root = path.resolve('./ditLogs');
    var fileName = req.query.file_name;
    var data;
    fs.readdir(dir, function(err, items) {
        items.forEach(function(file){
            if(fileName === file){
                data = file;
                console.log('DATA',data);
                res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + data);
                res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
                res.sendFile(data, {root: root});
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

Factory.js

```
 getFile:function(file_name){
            return $http.get("/file?file_name="+file_name);
        }
```

ctrl.js

```
$scope.downloadFile = function(message){
        DitFactory.getFile(message).then(function(response,$window){
            var data = JSON.stringify(response.data);
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' });
            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'text.txt');
            console.log(response.data.level);
        });
```

file.txt

```
{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}
{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}
{"level":"info","message":"Test Log  messages"}
```

Comment: You just asked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208285/how-to-create-object-when-you-read-multiples-lines-from-files-and-send-response) a [bunch of times](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6014098/hussain?tab=questions)

Comment: I asked that question but i thought i needed to explain more and more tags should be added with little more clarification that the reason i asked new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because the file is indeed not valid JSON.

You'll want to either parse the file and convert to an array, or send the file in plain text, and pass it through as-is to your file saver.

To parse your file, you can do:

```
data.split('\n').reduce(function (result, x) {
  x = x.trim();
  if (x) {
    result.push(x);
  }
  return result;
}, [])
```